# Problems with Swift 3 dev toolchain

Tags: swift

I have installed Swift from the dev downloads and am currently using

```
swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-04-12-a-ubuntu14.04
```

When I run

```
swift build
```

I get this terse message:

```
error: invalid inferred toolchain
```

I have had this configuration running earlier this week, but I seem to have broken something.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 11):

Did you install the [required dependencies](https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads)?

```
sudo apt-get install clang libicu-dev
```

Comment: For those installing on ARM-based systems such as Pi3 or BBB, use `clang-3.6` or higher here with `update-alternatives`.  See http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/error-invalid-inferred-toolchain/ for details (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: This is correct. In fact I had executed this command but because I forgot to `sudo apt-get update` before it, the installation had failed and I overlooked it...

Comment: does not help ... those ubuntu packages are installed still get swift build error

Comment: @ScottStensland This is for a development snapshot from mid-last year. I've had to use other packages for 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04, for example. Consider creating your own question, with your current circumstances, and a solution will probably be found.